# What effect in the current will have the change of the diameter of coil but same length of coil and same magnetic flux?

Tags: current, coil, magnetics, magnetic-flux

[image: 1]First image is one coil with the large diameter and a magnet rotating to create current in the coil. Second image is the same set but the diameter of coil is smaller.

Comment: More flux link with coil as you increase the diameter and hence amplitude of emf(as well as Current) induce in coil increases .

Comment: Neither of your pictures creates current in the coil. Voltage is induced but no current flows because there is no load on the coil. Voltmeters are very high impedance hence, no-loading effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will take the induced voltage as a criteria since that's the physical cause. A rotating magnet with a static coil should have the same characteristics as a rotating coil in a static magnetic field. The formula for the latter is generally known. The amplitude of the voltage is dependent on the number of turns, the diameter and the frequency. We are interested in the product of area times number of turns (A⋅N).

If you have a coil with diameter d and number of turns N, than the number of turn has to increases to k⋅N if you reduce the diameter to d/k (in order to keep the overall length the same). So the number of turns increases, but A=pi/4⋅d², which means the area is reduced bei 1/k².

Overall the product changes by k/k², thats equal to 1/k. This means the induced voltage will be reduced by a factor of 1/k if you reduce the diameter by 1/k.